# Delphi+Access: Несоответствие типов данных в выражении условия отбора.

Tags: access, delphi, sql

```
procedure TForm1.DBGrid1CellClick(Column: TColumn);
begin
  ADOQuery1.Active := false;
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM cars WHERE '+ Column.FieldName + '='+Edit1.Text);
  ADOQuery1.Active := true;
end;
```

В пятой строчке при клике по ячейке вылетает ошибка "Несоответствие типов данных в выражении условия отбора". Помогите исправить.

Comment: @Сергей , опишите структуру таблицы CARS.

Comment: Поле   Тип
id     Счетчик
number Текстовой
driver Текстовой
route  Текстовой
status Текстовой

Comment: По какому полю выбираете, какое значение Edit1.Text вводите? Какой запрос получается, если подебажить?

Comment: Как видите поле выборки выбирается налету, в едит вводится любое значение 1,2,3 итд. При: Label1.Caption := 'SELECT * FROM cars WHERE '+ Column.FieldName + '='+Edit1.Text; получается вполне корректный запрос - SELECT * FROM cars WHERE number=3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Аксессу как раз ругается на то, что вы пытаетесь текстовое поле Number сравнить с цифрой. Возьмите 3 в кавычки.

А лучше всего - используйте параметризованные запросы, явно указывая тип данных в условиях выборки.